# Create plot for every variable in data (all variables are categorical)

Tags: r, loops, plot

I am using the Soybean dataset from the mlbench package in R.

I want to show a frequency distribution by creating simple bar charts for each variable (all categorical). 
The plots should look something like this:

https://www.statmethods.net/graphs/images/barplot1.jpg

Many thanks in advance,
M

Answer (score 1):

If you want to graph all the variables one by one, you can use a loop on the colnames of your dataset. Use `ggplot()` and the function `get()` to focus on the name of the variable.

```
library(mlbench)
data(Soybean)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)       

for(j in 1:ncol(Soybean)){

  var <- colnames(Soybean)[j]

  Soybean %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = get(var))) + 
    geom_histogram(stat = 'count') +
    labs(x = 'var')

}
```

It will generate 36 graphes like this one:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your input. 

It did work well and was exactly what I was looking for. Again, many thanks. However, the computational time was higher than the method from the comment above.

Answer (score 1):

Using base R, you can get the desired result with:

```
my.barplot.function = function(x){ 
  heights = table(x)
  barplot(heights, names.arg = levels(x))
}

apply(Soybean, 2, my.barplot.function)
```

You will obtain plots such as the one below for all variables:

[image: Barplot for var 1]

Comment: thanks for your input. It worked very well. Great input, I very much appreciate your help.

Comment: @MLU : Glad to hear that it worked well for you. Even if it is not the top answer, please consider giving it an upvote if you found the code and the result useful for solving your problem and for future programming :)

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, you can also try `{purrr}` to apply a `{ggplot2}` process on every column of the data. I used `aes_string()` here so the column names can be passed as strings to the `ggplot` aesthetic.

Edit: Using gridExtra::marrangeGrob() to produce a 6 x 6 arrangement of all figures.

```
library(mlbench)
library(purrr)
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

data("Soybean")

marrangeGrob(
  map(
    names(Soybean), 
    ~ ggplot(Soybean, aes_string(.x)) + 
      geom_bar()
  ),
  ncol = 6,
  nrow = 6,
  top = "Soybean Distribution"
)
```

Comment: thank you for your input, this is exactly what I was looking for. However, I was thinking of creating a 6 x 6 plot space, so that I can view them all at the same time. Is there a way to incorporate this in your code? 

Many thanks in advance,

Comment: I edited the answer such that you'll get the 6 x 6 plot. I used gridExtra::marrangeGrob(). There is an increase in compute time, but I hope that is ok.